# Copy Ionic click function with ng2-dragula

Tags: function, ionic-framework, click, dragula

I want to copy an button with ionic function "(click)" from one bag to another with ng2-dragula

```
<div [dragula]='"fifth-bag"'>
  <button ion-button  (click)="addAtr()">
    <ion-icon name="person" ></ion-icon>
  </button> 
</div>
```

but after it's in the new bag it is not clickable any more. This only happens, when copy: true.

Anyone know what to do that dragula also copies the function?
Thanks

Comment: it seems like dragula not copies attributes in brackets